# JBoss is not able to write files to external nfs mount

Tags: java, spring, jboss, nfs

I have an nfs mount. I run JBoss and Spring/Java. As root, I am able to read/write files to the nfs shared location. JBoss is started as root. For some reason JBoss is unable to write to the nfs shared location. JBoss write operation does however write the new folder structure, but the actual file is not written to disk. JBoss is able to write anywhere else on local storage.

Any ideas? Does Java somehow write differently to local disk compared to nfs shared disk? It is also strange thtat the new folder structure is created, but the actual file is not.

Code that writes to nfs disk:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
out.write(content);
out.close();
```

Comment: You should not run JBoss as root. Are you sure that the files you have written are *really* closed *correctly* (in case of exceptions as).

Comment: it is perhaps not good practice to run JBoss as root, but can that be a root cause to this problem? There are not exceptions when closing. Also, java is able to write anywhere else, except for the nfs share.

Comment: AFAIK root privileges are not extended on an NFS mount (but you said explicitly that you could write as root to an NFS mounted directory). So yes, it could be the problem. Does it really work to write as root?

Comment: Yes, I am able to write to the NFS as root. JBoss (root) is also able to write new directories NFS, just not the files. I also tested with a pure .jar Java application that writes a file to NFS and it succeeded.  Only thing I noticed is that JBoss in this instance also renames the written file, could this be the problem? Is JBoss allowed to rename files on an NFS?

Comment: Who writes? JBoss or your application? If it's your application, please show the code. Is JBoss running from the NFS mount?

Comment: I added the code original post. JBoss is not running from the NFS mount. JBoss runs in its own location, but writes to the NFS mount which it has access to in the file system.

Comment: This code is not correct: In case of an `IOException` in `write` the stream is not closed. It's another question, if this is really the problem. Is there really nothing on top of the `OutputStream` (another `BufferedOutputStream` etc.). Please show the complete code.